# How to perform this function call

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, function-call

Given the two operands

```
Eigen::Quaterniond eigen_quat;  
tf::Quaternion tf_quat;
```

And the function

```
void tf::quaternionEigenToTF (const Eigen::Quaterniond &e, tf::Quaternion &t)
```

How do you perform the function call?

I'm looking for a simple line of code that acts as an example on how to perform the function call; bit confused right now with *,&, const etc. Feel free to edit the question title.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It should be as simple as `quaternionEigenToTF( eigen_quat, tf_quat )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is the `&`?

In a function signature, the `&` character means that it's taking that parameter by reference. This is useful because it allows the code to avoid copying big values, or because you want to modify a value in a function. For example:

```
void addOne(int& i) {
    i += 1; 
}

int main() {
    int x = 10; 

    addOne(x); // increments x by one
    
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // Prints 11
}
```

Because we took `x` by reference, when we modified `x` inside the function, the original value of `x` was modified too.

### What is the `const`?

When a variable is declared as `const`, that means that you can't modify it. For example:

```
const int x = 5;

x = 6; // ERROR: can't modify a const variable
```

If you have a `const` reference, that means that it's a reference to the variable, but you can't modify the variable through that reference. For example:

```
int x = 4;

x++; // It's fine to modify x

const int& x_ref = x; // Get a const reference to x

x_ref++; //Can't modify x_ref: x_ref is const
```

### Why use a const ref as a function parameter?

You should use a const reference as a function parameter when you have an object that's expensive to copy, but you want to guarantee that it won't be modified by the function you're passing it to.

The function you gave takes a `Eigen::Quaterniond` by const reference, avoiding copying, but guaranteed the user that the `Eigen::Quaternoind` object won't be modified by the function.

```
void tf::quaternionEigenToTF (const Eigen::Quaterniond &e, tf::Quaternion &t)
```

### How do I call it?

You can call it like any other function:

```
igen::Quaterniond eigen_quat;  
tf::Quaternion tf_quat;

// Call the function
tf::quaternionEigenToTF (eigen_quat, tf_quat);
```

Comment: A bit more on references: a C++ reference is not a variable. It is another name for an existing variable, so unlike pointers where you are passing around a variable that contains the address of another variable, a reference IS the other variable.

Comment: Thank you for the great and extremely simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

A reference - & - its as if you're giving two variables a different end of the same stick. They both look different, but are in fact the same thing underneath. You use it like you do an ordinary variable:

```
    int var{10};
    int & same_var = var; // Reference to var
    std::cout << same_var << std::endl; // Prints 10
    same_var += 10; // Both same_var and var get modified,
                    // as they're both sharing the same state
    std::cout << same_var << std::endl; // Prints 20
```

A pointer - * - This bad boy is a new block of memory, that contains the address of the thing it's pointing at. You can get a reference (&) to the object it's pointing at by dereferencing it:

```
    int var {1};
    int * ptr = &var; // Take the address of var, store it in a pointer
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; // Dereference the pointer - prints '1'
```

Now that you can see how we make pointers and references, you can look at calling this function.

```
void tf::quaternionEigenToTF (const Eigen::Quaterniond &e, tf::Quaternion &t)
```

This function takes 2 paramaters, one const Eigen::Quaterniond reference, and one tf::Quaternion reference.

Both of these objects are references, so as we saw above, they are different names for the same objects, eigen_quat and tf_quat in your case.

The const qualifier means that the function promises not to edit the state of the object you pass in (The compiler enforces this by not allowing it to call any non-const member functions on the const object).

So let's get down to business!

By doing a bit of copy-paste wizardry from [0x499602D2's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) answer:

```
quaternionEigenToTF( eigen_quat, tf_quat )
```

we can easily call this function by passing both objects as parameters. The reference-taking part happens by magic!